# Java, Maven: SLF4J error during build

Tags: java, maven, log4j, dependencies, slf4j

I'm working on a Java project and building it with Maven (m2e).  When I do a `mvn clean install` I get this error first thing:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

First thing is that the logging seems to be fine (it's very basic).  But I don't like errors in my build so I followed the URL.  It says basically that the class can be found in one of several packages, so I added `slf4j-simple` to my dependencies.  I didn't know which version to use, so I got the latest (1.7.1).  The error didn't go away.

It seems that one of my dependencies (JXL) needs `log4j` version 1.2.14 and this is what needs `slf4j`.  I don't think I can change this (can I?).  My thought is that maybe the `slf4j` is the wrong version but I don't know how to figure out what version `log4j` needs.

So first, do I even have a problem?  And second, even if I don't, is there a way to get rid of the warnings?

Here is the output of `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ dpt ---
[INFO] com.nike.dpt:dpt:war:1.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin:jar:6.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.vaadin.addons:filteringtable:jar:0.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.vaadin.addons:popupbutton:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile
```

I am running in the Eclipse (Juno) IDE using the Maven plugin (m2e).  The CLI I am using for Maven is `mvn clean package taomcat7:run` or `mvn clean install tomcat7:run`.  When I invoke Maven from a command line I do *not* see the slf4j error, so maybe this has to do with the `m2e` or Eclipse setup.

Comment: Did you include SLF4J in maven dependency and for deploy path, it seems SLF4J is not found in deployment folder.

Comment: I'm not sure what the deployment folder is, sorry.  I'm in Eclipse and I can see the slf4j jar under Maven Dependencies.

Comment: Artifact, when you deploy the project, you need to copy all required libs under WEB-INF/lib folder. If it is not found there then jar is missing

Comment: The jar definitely is in `target/dpt/WEB-INF/lib'.  Is there somewhere else to look?

Comment: If you do not change web server output folder then the folder should be: `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\your_app_name\WEB-INF\lib` You can go and check it

Comment: `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core` is empty.  Would a change of web server output folder be in the `maven-war-plugin` section?  I don't see any `<outputDirectory>` tab there.

Comment: How are you building the project with maven or with eclipse?

Comment: It happens with Eclipse and m2e but not with `mvn install` at the command line.  Is it an m2e problem?

Comment: Please provide more info on your runtime environment. Which server app server are you deploying with?

Comment: Maybe that is not a solution at all, but I was able to help myself by running my project using Apache tomcad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is not related to your project. It is an m2e problem and does not cause any harm. You won't see it if you build on the command-line outside Eclipse.

There is a bug about this but unfortunately they are rather willing to confuse peole than to fix it:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387064

Answer (score 1):

The output of `mvn dependency:tree` clearly shows that both slf4j-api and slf4j-simple are on your class path. The fact that SLF4J complains about not finding `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` means that there is another copy of *slf4j-api.jar* somewhere on your classpath and this is the copy being loaded into memory (rather than the copy of *slf4j-api.jar* in *com.nike.dpt:dpt:war*). Under such circumstances, because of the class loader delegation model of many application servers, the classes loaded by the server's copy of slf4j-api cannot find the classes packaged in *slf4j-simple.jar* located in your web-app. Typically this occurs when a copy of slf4j-api.jar is placed in the **application server**'s *lib/* folder as opposed to the *WEB-INF/lib/* folder of your web-application.

What is your runtime environment? application server?

Comment: I went into `target/dpt/WED-INF/lib` and I only saw `slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar` and `slf4j-simple-1.7.1.jar`.  Is this where I should look, or elsewhere?

Comment: The slf4j error code page say, "SLF4J API is desinged to bind with one and only one underlying logging framework at a time. If more than one binding is present on the class path, SLF4J will emit a warning, listing the location of those bindings."  I'm not seeing a list of locations, so can we assume that I don't have multiple jars?

Comment: You should look at your application server's lib/ folder. By app servers, I mean Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, Weblogic, etc. Hoint for the folders: $TOMCAT_HOME/lib, $JBOSS/server/lib/, $WEBLOGIC/some/path, etc. The error you are seeing seeing is reported when "the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory" because it could not be found. It is unrelated to multiple bindings.

Comment: I edited my question to include runtime environment.  I'm using a Maven plugin tomcat7.  I get the error only when I'm launching the app server from the IDE (Eclipse), not when I run Maven from the command line.  My CLI is `mvn clean package tomcat7:run`

Comment: Sounds like a bug in m2e or in the t7 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this rule:

```
Place one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure these dependencies in your pom:

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile
org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.1:runtime
```

slf4j-api is the log API and is needed in compile time, whereas slf4j-log4j12 is the implementation (using log4j) and it's needed in runtime.

Comment: You explanation is surprisingly plausible but unfortunately quite wrong. As far as I know, the "runtime" scope differs from "compile" in that a dependency in runtime scope is not transitive (which should not make a difference in this case). Thus, scoping slf4j-log4j as  runtime scope should have no impact on the problem at hand.